# No css in Django

Tags: css, django, apache

I deployed Django app localy on Apache server using mod_wsgi.
I can't see CSS. All previous posts are about admin, but I'm not using admin in my app.

Css files are in folder C:/Pakel/Resman/main/static/ so i added
Alias /static/ "C:/Pakel/Resman/main/static/" to httpd.conf

Comment: "All previous posts are about admin" - that is simply not true. Missing static assets is the single most frequently asked question about Django.

Comment: I'll check fo static assets keyword.

Comment: Found solution on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-development at Serving static files in development paragraph.

Comment: why -1? This is not easy to see the first time